# how to change Between Debug and Release programatically in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

want to change project settings programatically there are many settings like this

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
Project project = dte2.Solution.Projects.Item(1);
Configuration configuration = project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
configuration.Properties.Item("StartAction").Value = VSLangProj.prjStartAction.prjStartActionProgram;
configuration.Properties.Item("StartProgram").Value = "your exe file";
configuration.Properties.Item("StartArguments").Value = "command line arguments";
```

bu i cant find any option to switch between Debug and Release :

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? The configuration (ie: debug, release, etc) affects the entire build process which is why you specify it as a parameter to the build command. Afaik it doesn't make sense to programmatically change the build configuration during any process.

Comment: @TimothyJannace i need to build my asp project for different servers. the app works with different servers differently using conditional symbols. one of parameters that need to change is to change debug to publish. i need this process automated with only one button for more pacing and less mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (this was written for VS2019: check the GetActiveObject is right for you):

```
using EnvDTE80;
using System;

namespace SelectConfig
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChangeConfiguration("Release", "Any CPU");
        }
        private static void ChangeConfiguration(string configurationName, string platformName)
        {
            DTE2 dte2 = (DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.16.0");
            bool found = false;
            foreach (SolutionConfiguration2 configuration in dte2.Solution.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations)
            {
                if (configuration.Name == configurationName && configuration.PlatformName == platformName)
                {
                    configuration.Activate();
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
            {
                SolutionConfiguration2 finalConfig = (SolutionConfiguration2)dte2.Solution.SolutionBuild.ActiveConfiguration;
                Console.WriteLine($"End Configuration: {finalConfig.Name}/{finalConfig.PlatformName}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Requested configuration {configurationName}/{platformName} not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```